# How to get integration testing in PHP and Laravel to work with the Select2 JQuery plugin

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, phpunit

I'm using PHPUnit and Laravel 5 (with the Laracasts Integration package) to integration test a form within my web application. The form consists of three fields; Title, Description and Tags. All are input textfields with the exception of the Tags field which is a Select2 plugin with the tags option enabled.

Using PHPUnit and Laracasts Integration, I'm trying to submit the form with the following information:

```
$this->submitForm('Post Job', [
    'title'       => 'A test title',
    'description' => 'A test description',
    'tags'        => 'Tag1, Tag2, Tag3'
]);
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
There was 1 error:

1) PostAJobTest::it_successfully_posts_a_job
InvalidArgumentException: Input "tags" cannot take "Tag1, Tag2, Tag3" as a value (possible values: ).

/home/vagrant/Code/myproject/vendor/symfony/dom-crawler/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Field/ChoiceFormField.php:144
/home/vagrant/Code/myproject/vendor/symfony/dom-crawler/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/FormFieldRegistry.php:128
/home/vagrant/Code/myproject/vendor/symfony/dom-crawler/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Form.php:76
/home/vagrant/Code/myproject/vendor/laracasts/integrated/src/Extensions/IntegrationTrait.php:380
/home/vagrant/Code/myproject/vendor/laracasts/integrated/src/Extensions/Traits/LaravelTestCase.php:47
/home/vagrant/Code/myproject/tests/phpunit/HelpersTrait.php:107
/home/vagrant/Code/myproject/tests/phpunit/Functional/PostAJobTest.php:14
```

For reference, the JS of my Select2 element is:

```
$("#tags").select2({
    tags: true,
    tokenSeparators: [',', ','],
    maximumSelectionLength: 3,
    ajax: {
        url: "/api/tags",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                tag: params.term
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        id: item.id,
                        text: item.name
                    }
                 })
             };
        },
        cache: true
    }
});
```

It appears that the way the Tags field is input with 'Tag1, Tag2 and Tag3' isn't registering with Select2 and I cannot work out how to fix this?

Comment: Try setting it as an array `'tags'        => ['Tag1', 'Tag2', 'Tag3']`

Comment: Should have said I've tried that and it doesn't work

Comment: If you think about it, we're just trying to input data into a text field, why would we input data into a textfield in an array. The plugin will convert it into an array anyway. The issue is how we insert it into a field.

Comment: The plugin is simply a nice interface which controls an underlying select or multi-select box.  PHP doesn't care or know what's happening with select2, all it sees is that underlying select box so select2 can probably be ignored and we just set the values for the select.